# Xampp htdocs folder, sub folders and all files permission

Tags: permissions, filesystem, php, xampp

I am not familiar with Ubuntu. I copied my project folder in `htdocs`, then I open my project in browser it loads, but styling files (CSS files) don't load. It is a permission problem. I have done a lot of commands but didn't have any success.

How can I give permission to each and every thing in `htdocs`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to change permissions or ownership of htdocs directory. To change the permissions use the **chmod** command, for example:

```
$sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

To see who is currently logged user, run:

```
$whoami
```

To change the owner use the **chown** command:

```
$sudo chown -R username:username /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Also, you can use **find** command to change the permissions only on specific files. For example, to change the permissions on all css files in htdocs directory run the following command:

```
sudo find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -name "*.css"  -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Comment: whoami works for me

Comment: The above helped me place wordpress folder and start installation. But the directory was not writable. I had to chmod777 before successfully complete the installation and using the directory inside wordpress.

Comment: I copied mypage.php to htdocs and it has rwx--x--- rights. I see xampp index.html has 644. Where do I set umask so when copying to htcdocs my files shange to 644 rights?

Comment: you need to do a sudo -i before all

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R daemon wordpress-folder

// or use htdocs folder
```

the xampp apache server uses a user named daemon to access the folders inside htdocs, this will fix all the permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

That's what helped me:

`sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /opt/lampp/htdocs`

Also you can make changes in `httpd.conf` file:

`sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`